# How do I check if the system date is correct in flutter? Any package or API

Tags: flutter, api, datetime, system

Is there any way to check if the system DateTime is correct or not in Flutter? I tried searching for APIs which provide current DateTime, but the problem with timezones happens again. What is the solution for this? (I want to do something like WhatsApp. which is, don't give chatting access if system DateTime is wrong)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simple solution, use unix epoch time

```
print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: This prints the system time in milliSecondSinceEpoch format. If the system time is incorrect, it prints that incorrect time.

Comment: we use unix epoch time to avoid the time zone issues you are having in your post, we compare the system unix epoch time to any external source to verify that the system unix epoch time is correct. this should be a really simple task for you to achieve,

Comment: Can you name some external sources, from which I can get Unix epoch time? I'll send 2k requests per hour on average.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ntp](https://pub.dev/packages/ntp) plugin

```
var nowInternet = await NTP.now();
var now = DateTime.now();
print(nowInternet);
print(now);
//check diff is grater than 1 minute
if (nowInternet.difference(now).inMinutes < 1){
   //good
}
```